# Why is a constructor of a initialized instance field called twice in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, constructor

This is the simplified version of what I did.

The service class(which has no subclass):

```
public class SomeService{

    @autowired
    SomeOtherService someOtherService;

    private final ClassA aInstance = new ClasseA(“str1“, “str2“);

    public void businessLogic(){
        // logic is here
    }
}
```

The class of the instance field:

```
public class ClassA{
    String p1;
    String p2;

    public ClassA(String p1, String p2){
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;

        // log is here
    }
}
```

When I ran the above code in Junit test, the log in the constructor was printed twice. What possibly caused this?

BTW, the controller calling the service instance method is @transactional and the log only show up once when I did this.

```
public class SomeService{

    @autowired
    SomeOtherService someOtherService;

    private ClassA aInstance;

    public void businessLogic(){
         
        aInstance = new ClasseA(“str1“, “str2“);

        // logic is here
    }
}
```

Edited: Based on the comment by Deinum, this is likely to be a Spring Boot specific problem. Any possible cause with clear explanation is appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Because you probably have something like `@Transactional` or something else that will trigger proxy creation. Spring Boot uses class bases proxies so you get 2 instances. When the field is not initialized in the constructor that means 2 instances will be created, when in the constructor, the creation is intercepted and there will only be 1 instance.

Comment: Thank you, Deinum. Yes, @Transactional was applied in the controller calling the service instance method.